# UseEffect/useCallback is not triggering on very fast changes

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I'm a Backend Dev and having limited knowledge in React still have to fix the problem

My project uses WebRTC for video calls. For signaling I'm using SignalR on my .NET backend.
On the frontend I have 2 classes:

**signalRContext.tsx** which holds an instance of HubConnection and listeners, onmessage is the relevant one.

```
const [currentSignal, setCurrentSignal] = useState<TCurrentSignal>
(InitialSignalR.currentSignal);    

const initializeSignalListeners = (connection: HubConnection): void => {
console.log('START SIGNAL_R', connection);

connection.on('master', function (RoundInfo: IRoundInfo) {
  console.log('MASTER', RoundInfo);
  setCurrentSignal({ type: 'master', payload: RoundInfo });
});

connection.on('slave', function (RoundInfo: IRoundInfo) {
  console.log('SLAVE', RoundInfo);
  setCurrentSignal({ type: 'slave', payload: RoundInfo });
});

connection.on('message', function (message: TSignalRMessage) {
  console.log('MESSAGE', message);
  setCurrentSignal({ type: 'message', payload: message });
});

connection.on('endround', (payload) => {
  console.log('END_ROUND');
  setCurrentSignal({ type: 'endround', payload });
});
```

**useRTCPeerConnection.ts** which has the whole WebRtc relevant logic

```
import { useSignalRContext } from '../../../../core/contexts';

const {
  signalrRRef,
  currentSignal: { type, payload },
} = useSignalRContext();

useCallback(() => { //tried UseEffect as well
    if (type === 'message') {
      console.log('PAYLOAD', payload);
      onMessage(payload as TSignalRMessage);
      return;
    }
  }, [type, payload]);
```

My problem starts when WebRTC starts exchanging the ICE candidates and sends them sometimes twice per millisecond (see the last column).
The `connection.on('message'...` listener seems to be fast enough, I'm seeing all `console.log('MESSAGE'...` outputs in the console.
My problem is that the `useCallback/useEffect` logic is not firing on every payload change, like for 20 MESSAGE outputs I'm seeing 4-7 PAYLOAD outputs.
My assumption is that useEffect is simply not designed for such quick changes.

Is there any other concept better suitable to solve this problem or any improvement I could do here? Thinking on .NET I would just use the composition pattern and call the relevant method from peer connection class within the event handler in signalR class but not sure how to fix it here.

[image]

P.S. I've tried to wait until ICE candidates are gathered and sending them at once but the performance becomes not acceptable.

Comment: We really need more information here... Altough the frequency of the changes are indeed fast I don't believe that's the problem. How you're using the custom hook inside your components, how the context is changed between events. Are you calling the listeners sequencially or just ovewriting them (which I believe it's the case here) could you share a reproducible example?

Comment: something to consider as well, `setCurrentSignal()` updates the value of `currentSignal` asynchronously. You can test this by adding `console.log("currentSignal", currentSignal)` right after calling `setCurrentSignal()`

Comment: @Dupocas can you please point me out how it looks like what to share? As I've mentioned I'm not a frontend dev and just have not much understanding about react, that's why the reproducable example is also hard to achieve. Thanks a lot

Comment: useEffect executes the effect after the component rendering. If you have multiple messages per millisecond, react will probably batch multiple calls to `setCurrentSignal` into a single one. As a result there will probably be fewer rendering than received messages. If you want to execute a callback for each message, why not passing the callback `onMessage` as a parameter of `useSignalRContext` and using it inside this custom hook ?

Comment: React will not batch setState calls, but it will skip console logs. There's a very good resource for that here on SO, but I can't find it. I think this might be a misuse of useState though, it doesn't seem that there's any UI relying on this state. Why not pass onMessage to your hook? (as @OlivierBoissé mentions)

Comment: @VladL I would start by instead of logging the messages setting up a counter to increment at each event and then print the counter at the end.

Comment: thanks, we've ended up rewriting the code splitting signaling + rtc from the view-related stuff